# How to control a python shell using a script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to launch a python script from an app (Java). The said script opens a python shell and there are a few commands that I want to run on that shell. How do I achieve this? Is this even possible?

Comment: It's probably possible. There are various "special" python shells, such as ipython etc. But I suspect that it's not trivial to implement. What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I have a few python scripts, want to execute them and capture the output, from an app. I just give a command as the input

Comment: You can write a python script that prints its output to stdout using `print`. This can be used in unix pipes, so I assume it should be straightforward to do it from java as well. Python scripts can take arguments from stdin by using [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Comment: I have a script that opens up a terminal and I need to access that whenever a command is triggered and need to get the output, all this using the same terminal. I'm not sure how this can be achieved using a simple stdout

Comment: What code do you have so far? You can edit the question to add detail. And you should maybe add the tag "java" as well.

Comment: Pass `-u` option to `python` executable, to disable block-buffering  (and perhaps `-i`, to simplify the Python script itself). Otherwise, controlling `python` is no different than controlling any other interactive command i.e., it is a [tag:java] question, not [tag:python]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *is* possible; I have done it before and  I used [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/).  You can install it using `pip` or `easy_install`.